# As a noun, does the word 'laic' operate as a synonym for the word 'layperson'?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Based off of my Internet searches, it is not quite clear to me in what way this word operates.

Collins Dictionary, according to the page at which I looked when I looked up the word 'laic', said that the word 'laic' can operate as a synonym for 'layperson' in a clerical and non-clerical sense; but, according to Oxford Dictionary and some other dictionaries, the word 'laic' only operates as a synonym for 'layperson' in the clerical sense.

For example, would it be correct, if one didn't want to use the word 'layperson', to say: "no, my explaining that sort of thing to you would be an impossibility, as I am a total laic when it comes to this matter".

Can someone please clarify this for me, please?

Answer (score 0):

## *laik* is 100–10,000 times rarer than *layman*

“No one” would know what you’re talking about because *laic* is **two to four *orders of magnitude* less common** than *layman* is according to the OED. It is a rare word seldom seen outside of ecclesiastical writings.

The OED says that *layman* occurs one to ten times per million words, while *laic* occurs only between one **in** ten and one **in** a hundred times **per million words**.

---

## Sage Advice

One writeth not the word *laic* in general text lest the laity know not what one writeth.

> #### BECKET.
>
> I do believe thee, then. I am the man.
>   And yet I seem appall’d—on such a sudden
>   At such an eagle-height I stand and see
>   The rift that runs between me and the King.
>   I served our Theobald well when I was with him;
>   I served King Henry well as Chancellor;
>   I am his no more, and I must serve the Church.
>   This Canterbury is only less than Rome,
>   And all my doubts I fling from me like dust,
>   Winnow and scatter all scruples to the wind,
>   And all the puissance of the warrior,
>   And all the wisdom of the Chancellor,
>   And all the heap’d experiences of life,
>   I cast upon the side of Canterbury—
>   Our holy mother Canterbury, who sits
>   With tatter’d robes. **Laics** and barons, thro’
>   The random gifts of careless kings, have graspt
>   Her livings, her advowsons, granges, farms,
>   And goodly acres—we will make her whole;
>   Not one rood lost. And for these Royal customs,
>   These ancient Royal customs—they *are* Royal,
>   Not of the Church—and let them be anathema,
>   And all that speak for them anathema.
>
> #### HERBERT.
>
> Thomas, thou art moved too much.

—Tennyson, *Beckett*, Act I, Scene I

Comment: Bearing that in mind, though, can one use the word 'laic' as a synonym for the word 'layperson' or not?

Comment: @OneWhoBelievesInPeace Art thou writing of *roods* and *advowsons*, and art thou writing *thou art* and *I do believe thee* as Lord Tennyson hath writ? If so, then by all means go ahead and do so. But if you aren’t, then you probably should not unless your intent is to confuse nearly everybody. Is that your goal?

Comment: It's a shame that the first word of this answer is *laik* !